# verbatiminput formatting of gretl output, minus sign missing

Tags: verbatim, characters

I'm preparing econometrics tutorials and this year we changed the software (now using gretl).
I want to include regression output from a text file.

However, the `\verbatiminput` command does not preserve the original formatting, the minus sign gets lost.

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.txt}
Model 1: OLS, using observations 1913-1984 (T = 72)
Dependent variable: fertil

             coefficient   std. error   t-ratio    p-value 
  ---------------------------------------------------------
  const       98.6818      3.20813      30.76     1.25e-041 ***
  taxex        0.0825400   0.0296462     2.784    0.0069    ***
  ww2        -24.2384      7.45825      -3.250    0.0018    ***
  pill       -31.5940      4.08107      -7.742    6.46e-011 ***

Mean dependent var   95.63194   S.D. dependent var   19.80464
Sum squared resid    14664.27   S.E. of regression   14.68506
R-squared            0.473415   Adjusted R-squared   0.450184
F(3, 68)             20.37801   P-value(F)           1.57e-09
Log-likelihood      -293.5577   Akaike criterion     595.1154
Schwarz criterion    604.2221   Hannan-Quinn         598.7408
rho                  0.890457   Durbin-Watson        0.176873
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\verbatiminput{test.txt}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[output http://www.pichost.de/images/2015/04/10/PZRO.png](http://www.pichost.de/images/2015/04/10/PZRO.png)

How can I include the text file such that original format is conserved?

Comment: Those minuses seem like they're the cause of the problem. Are you sure they are `-` or perhaps something else?

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Indeed, If I remove them everything is fine. Actually, this is exactly the output from gretl..

Comment: Well, they're important. But they should be `-`, not something else that looks like `-` (whatever that may be).

Comment: For now I'll just search and replace the symbol. Will send a bug report to gretl. Thank you very much!

Comment: If I run the document as posted above the - signs all appear and alignment is preserved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gretl developer here. Here's the story: gretl has used (for a few years now) the Unicode character 2212 for the minus sign if the output terminal supports Unicode.
This is typographically correct (see for example [here](http://www.punctuationmatters.com/the-difference-between-a-dash-and-a-minus-sign/)), but doesn't play nice with LaTeX because of its awkward relationships with Unicode: the solution I use is to put the two lines

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
```

in the LaTeX preamble, so that it's the inputenc package that takes care of everything.